# Using grep to find substring between two string variables that contain paths

Tags: shell-script, grep

I simply want to confirm that a path exists in another path using string variables.

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash

HAYSTACK="/cygdrive/d/var/www/html/adm4"
NEEDLE="/cygdrive/d/var/www/html"

# first try
#grep -q "$NEEDLE" "$HAYSTACK"

#second try
grep -q "${NEEDLE}" "${HAYSTACK}"

if [ $? -eq 0 ] ; then
    echo  "Your string has been found"
else
    echo "Your string has not been found"
fi
```

Results:

```
me@localhost ~]$ ./testbash
grep: : No such file or directory
Your string has not been found
```

I suspect that because these are paths, I need to do a little more.

Comment: `$HAYSTACK` is empty.

Comment: Updated my script... DEPLOY_PATH became HAYSTACK. I get the same error (with HAYSTACK not being found). It should only be evaluated as strings, not as actual paths.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grep is expecting the command in the format `grep [options] PATTERN [FILE...]` so treats the second string as a file to scan through. If it's just the one line, you can send it it on stdin.

```
echo $haystack | grep $needle
```

Or however you'd prefer. Maybe with a here string:

```
grep $needle <<< $haystack
```

Comment: This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Bash has built-in pattern matching with the `==` comparison operator when using the `[[ ]]` form, so you could do something like this to avoid calling grep altogether:

```
if [[ $HAYSTACK == *${NEEDLE}* ]] ; then
    echo "Your string has been found"
else
    echo "Your string has not been found"
fi
```

If you need to perform a more complex match, Bash also supports regular expression matching with the `=~` operator.

Comment: What about if I wanted to test for a string directly without the NEEDLE variable? == "*/path/here*" ?

Comment: You can replace `*${NEEDLE}*` with whatever you want to compare against. If you enclose it with quotes, it will be taken as a literal string; without quotes (as in the example above), it will be treated as a pattern and wildcards `*` and `?` will be expanded if present. Variable expansion follows the usual rules.